# Rails - Posts with most comments in last 6 hours ordered by comments count

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I can get easily find posts that have been commented on in the last 6 hours. However, I don't know how to order those posts by the number of comments made in the last 6 hours.

This is all I have:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: {created_at: 6.hours.ago...Time.now})
```

How do I order it? If the best way is to use a SQL query, I'm using PostgreSQL if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want something like this:

```
Post.joins(:comments).where('comments.created_at BETWEEN ? AND ?', 6.hours.ago, Time.now).group('posts.id').order('COUNT(comments.id)')
```

If your requirement is different then feel free to comment and I will try to modify the answer.

Comment: The order bit isn't working. It returns the posts fine without it, but outputs nothing if I include it

Comment: What do you mean by nothing ? returns 0 record or something like error ? .I tested in MySql , it was fine. So something with postgres maybe. Can you run it in console and see what SQL it generates ?

Comment: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."commentable_id" = "posts"."id" AND "comments"."commentable_type" = $1 WHERE (comments.created_at BETWEEN '2017-02-03 06:25:12.344465' AND '2017-02-03 12:25:12.344837') ORDER BY COUNT(comments.id)  [["commentable_type", "Post"]]
    => #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x2ac4449543a8>

Comment: Added a `group by` , it fixed problem in my case and still untested in PG. You can test this now.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be easiest for you to create a helper method for your Post model which returns the comments count:

```
def comments_count
  comments.count
end
```

You can now do:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(created_at: 6.hours.ago...Time.now).order(:comments_count)
```

It might be possible to do it without the helper method, I'm not sure but if you wanted to try:

```
Post.includes(:comments).where(created_at: 6.hours.ago...Time.now).order(:comments.count)
```

Comment: NoMethodError: undefined method `count' for :comments:Symbol